# Using mocked method argument to mock next steps

Tags: java, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocking, mockito

I have a method in my code that looks something like this:

```
action.onResult(new Handler<MyClass>() {
        @Override
        public MyClass handle() { // Do something here }
     }
}
```

I want to be able to mock it (using Mockito). Something like this:

```
when(mockedAction.onResult(any(Handler.class))).thenReturn(firstArg.handle());
```

Meaning, I want to call the `handle` method of the argument that's sent to the method `onResult`. I can't mock the handler because it uses inner methods of the calling class (I thought about using a private class but haven't reached a good enough solution)

**Motivation**: This is an asynchronous callback mechanism that's used in a synchronous area.  I want to mock the call to the handler itself in order to continue the flow synchronously in the code.

Comment: Hmm, there is `ArgumentCaptor` which may do that but I have never tried to use it this way... I generally use it on `verify` to inspect the value the mock has been invoked with

Comment: @fge - Looks interesting. Might be what I need. I'm checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, UNTESTED but here is a possible use of `ArgumentCaptor` for this scenario:

```
final ArgumentCaptor<Handler> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Handler.class);

when(mock.onResult(captor.capture())).thenReturn(captor.getValue().handle());
```

Not sure however whether the captor has the "time" to initialize here.

Comment: It worked :) Had to struggle a bit more because `onResult` is void and I couldn't remember how to test void. But that's irrelevant to this question and I managed to do it using your suggestion. Thanks!